# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setErrors is not a function Basic useState Question

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning states I wanted to know why do I get this error and how should I handle this error.

```js
const PCD = () => {
  const [setErrors] = useState(false);
  const [git, setGit] = useState([]);

  async function fetchData() {
    const res = await fetch("https://api.github.com/users/ethanolle/repos");
    res
      .json()
      .then((res) => setGit(res))
      .catch((err) => setErrors(err));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  });
```

error:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setErrors is not a function Basic useState Question

Comment: You need `const [errors, setErrors] = ` - the first value is the current value of the state, not the updater function.

Comment: You need to add two values to the first state declaration. const [errors, setErrors] similar to the one below.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> const [setErrors] = useState(false);
> const [git, setGit] = useState([]);
> ```

Compare your two uses of `useState`. You got it right the *second* time!

`useState` returns an array containing **two** values.

The first value is the variable that holds the current state.

The **second** value is the setter function.

You're only creating a variable for one of them, the first one.

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState(false);
```